# CSS selector style exclusion for some selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have

```
<table id="exclude1"><tr><td id="exclude2" height="100%" width="100%">

    <div>123</div><table>......</table> etc

</td></tr></table>
```

and CSS style

```
<style>
#exclude1, #exclude2 {border:0; background:transparent; width:100%; height:100%; margin:auto; padding:0; float:none; position:relative;}
* {border:1px solid red; background:red; width:100px; etc.....}
</style>
```

The problem is, when I set 'display:block' or 'display:inline' for '*' selector is css, then this style also applies to excluded selectors. 
When I set 'display:block' or 'table', or 'table-cell' or whatever for the 'exclude' selectors, these two elements become different (alignment, size etc are ruined).

What can I do, to make #exclude1 and #exclude2 untouched by '*' selector styles?

UPD:

I've separated #exclude1, #exclude2 as:

```
#exclude1 {border:0; background:transparent; width:100%; height:100%; margin:auto; padding:0; float:none; position:relative; display:table;}
#exclude2 {border:0; background:transparent; width:100%; height:100%; margin:auto; padding:0; float:none; position:relative; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
```

and seems like all works fine at least for now. 
Thanx.

Comment: Why are you applying those properties to everything? Why must everything be a red box?

Comment: `#exclude1` should be `display:table` and `#exclude2` should be `display:table-cell`

Comment: @BoltClock: that just an example. Simplified.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: after that they loose vertical alignment (even with 'vertical-align:middle' enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put * before #Exclude1, #Exclude2.
Thats how CSS works, they're **Cascading** Style Sheets.

And, if all else fails, throw a !important after your property like this:

- border: none !important;

Comment: There is a lot of easy to understand information about how CSS works in slideshow form on this page, http://www.slideshare.net/webdevninja/how-css-works